# SQL Query: Group Time into timeslices then group by loginname then count distinct loginnames per timeslice

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a huge table containing starting times of the operation (starttime) +  the user who started it (loginname) + a lot of date which is uninportant for the query i need.

From that i want to group the time into 10 min intervals and then get a count of distinct loginnames for that 10 min timeslice.

So far i have this:

```
SELECT
to_timestamp( extract ( 'epoch' from starttime)::int / (600) * 600 ) AS timeslice,
loginname
from request
where starttime >= '2013-06-11 00:00:00' and starttime < '2013-06-11 01:00:00'
group by timeslice, loginname
order by timeslice asc
```

which gives me the 10 min timeslices with one row per unique user, how do i get one row per timeslice with the count of unique users?

I have some ideas, but they are not pretty/fast ... and i want to learn to make better/faster querys if possible ;-)

Datebase is a PostgreSQL 8.1.18 on RHEL 5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    to_timestamp(extract('epoch' from starttime)::int / 600 * 600) AS timeslice,
    count(distinct loginname) total
from request
where starttime >= '2013-06-11 00:00:00' and starttime < '2013-06-11 01:00:00'
group by timeslice
order by timeslice asc
```

Comment: well that was easy ... thanks :) (i think the as before total is missing ;-) )

Comment: @Patrick The `as` is syntax sugar although some will argue that it is recommended.